# How can I prevent a second user from overwriting an entity property(column) in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency, database-concurrency, concurrency-exception

If I have an entity called "Lesson" and it has an InstructorId as one of it's fields(columns) and I only want 1 instructor being able to register, do I need to create a concurrency token and catch a "DbConcurrencyException" if there is a value?

Ex. 2 instructors enter the controller "RegisterInstructor()", they fetch Lesson and see if there is a value in InstructorId or not, if they both see null they proceed to register. One finishes registering first and now has a value in the DB table Lesson for the InstructorId, but now the second instructor saves and his/her InstructorId will overwrite the first instructors id.

Question - To prevent this, do I need to create a property "version" and set it as a concurrency token so that if there is already an InstructorId in the table, it will throw an db concurrency exception or is there an easier/different way?

```
public class Lesson {
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Lesson>()
  .Property(p => p.Version)
  .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Now that I think about it, do I even need a new column/property? Can't I just set the InstructorId column as the ConcurrencyToken() in the OnModelCreating()?

Comment: Databases typically offer an in-built RowVersion capability like Timestamp in SQL Server that EF can map to and use via `IsRowVersion()` or `[Timestamp]` attribute. This is generally better than using the ConcurrencyToken which EF filters in the `Where` clauses as doing it automatically at the DB version handles all cases where a row might be updated where concurrency check fields like "Version" need to be updated manually.

Comment: so for my scenario, you think IsRowVersion is better?

Comment: Won't a timestamp be updated every time the entity Lesson is modified?

Comment: Yes, a timestamp will be updated with each update, regardless of what changed, and what triggered the change.

Comment: [Here's the field you need to add to your entity](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/c06afce01bf1fd79dc2abdf0c40c9cf5b00ac945/MintPlayer.Data/Entities/Subject.cs#L23) - You just send this stamp back from your frontend to your backend - [Here you check if the stamp is still the same](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/c06afce01bf1fd79dc2abdf0c40c9cf5b00ac945/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/SongRepository.cs#L224). A way to resolve the  onflicts is not yet implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a Timestamp and instead only want to ensure that an instructor can only be assigned once or otherwise avoid a race condition on that assignment, then an option would be to use an isolated check and update with a specific WHERE clause similar to a concurrency token. One issue with concurrency checks like this is that even if you reload an entity there will always be a window of time, albeit small, where two updates could possibly done leading to a data overwrite. With EF Core 7 there is an `ExecuteUpdate()` method that can help:

```
// given we already have the Lesson loaded in a tracked "lesson" entity:

using (var innerContext = _contextFactory.Create())
{
    var rowsUpdated = innerContext.Lessons
        .Where(x => x.LessonId == lesson.LessonId && !x.InstructorId.HasValue)
        .ExecuteUpdate(u => u.SetProperty(x => x.InstructorId, myInstructorId));
    if (rowsUpdated == 0)
         // Handle notifying the user that the item could not be updated.
}   
context.Entry(lesson).Load(); // Reload our tracled entity to reflect any change / current state.
```

You could execute this on the main DbContext instance, but ExecuteUpdate does not update change tracking and should not be mixed in the event you want to use  `SaveChanges`. So the above example uses an isolated DbContext instance. The main DbContext instance (context) then needs to reload it's current state to reflect the change or the fact that nothing was updated due to a failed race. This example only updates the instructor ID if one hasn't been set. If instructors can change the instructor for a lesson, just you want to guard against the race condition, then change: `.Where(x => x.LessonId == lesson.LessonId && !x.InstructorId.HasValue)` to `.Where(x => x.LessonId == lesson.LessonId && x.InstructorId <> lesson.InstructorId)`

That may need additional #null comparison handling, I cannot remember if `<>` works with #null.